# Microsoft.JSInterop.JSException: Could not find <js function name> when run on IIS

Tags: iis, blazor

I am developing a Blazor Server App that calls some functions in a `.js` file.

The app works without any issues when run through Visual Studio on the development machine.

When I publish the app to a folder and copy that folder to a web server (Windows 2019) running IIS 7, I am able to access the app from the browser within the server itself, with no errors.

Only when I try to access the app from a remote machine, the app loads the `Index.razor` but displays an Error: `Error: Microsoft.JSInterop.JSException: Could not find <js method name>`.

I tried to access the Javascript file by typing its URL on the remote browser, and the file loaded and I could see all the Javascript functions that are reported not found.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you call the function from the dev tools console?

Comment: @KurtHamilton dev tools are disabled by the administrator. The error is logged into a text file on the server.

Comment: @KurtHamilton I don't see why devtools are relevant. javascript file is loaded normally when accessed from the server. If the files is loaded on one machine, why can't it be loaded on a different machine?

Comment: Probably a cached js file problem. Try a forced refresh on the page.

Comment: Check to see if there are any network or firewall issues preventing the remote computer from accessing the JavaScript file. Make sure the server can be accessed from the remote computer and that there are no restrictions blocking communication.

Comment: @PaulDurant Your suggestion helped me. I cleared browsing history and it worked. Thanks.